# Why does my for loop always return 'False'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, palindrome

Here is the given task: Write a function that receives two words, in string format, s1 and s2.

It should return True, if s1 and s2 are palindromes, and False otherwise.

I started by converting the strings to lists. Then, I check if the 1st string (now converted to a list) is a palindrome, followed by the second string (also converted to a list). Eventually, I form a boolean that returns True if both lists are palindromic, and False otherwise. However, when I input strings with both words being palindromic (kayak and madam), it returns False. Could you provide some guidance on this?

Here is my code:

```
def palindrome(s1, s2):
    convert_s1 = list(s1)
    convert_s2 = list(s2)
    for letter in [convert_s1]:
        n = 0
        if convert_s1[n] == convert_s1[-(n+1)]:
            is_s1_palindrome = True 
        else:
            is_s1_palindrome = False 
    for letter in [convert_s2]:
        m = 0
        if convert_s2[m] == convert_s1[-(m+1)]:
            is_s2_palindrome = True
        else:
            is_s1_palindrome = False
    if (is_s1_palindrome == True) and (is_s2_palindrome == True):
        both_pals = True
    else: 
        both_pals = False
    return both_pals
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: for me your code is working correctly

Comment: Works fine on my computer too.

Comment: There are many issues with your code, and I suggest you start with some tutorials to understand what your current code is doing.

Comment: For those who think the code is working, try it with `abca`, I'm pretty certain that's *not* a palindrome :-) Also, unless your strings are equal, I'm pretty sure being palindromic won't help either.

Comment: BTW, I voted to re-open this. The proposed dupe is fine if the question was "how do I check for palindromes?" but *this* question was "why is my code wrong?". If you're wondering why, it's because I would prefer to educate those wanting to learn rather than just give them a canned solution. Especially since using such a canned solution would probably get them penalised for plagiarism :-)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting false all the time is almost certainly due to the fact that your second comparison is using `s2` and `s1`:

```py
if convert_s2[m] == convert_s1[-(m+1)]:
```

That means you *will* always get false except, I think, for very rare cases like the collections being both palindromic *and* identical.

Also, you seem to set `is_s2_palindromic` for the true case and `is_s1_palindromic` for the false case. I'm not convinced that was intended.

---

If your intent is just to fix that *specific* problem, you can probably stop reading now.

But there are other issues as well that you may want to consider. First, this code is not correct:

```py
if convert_s1[n] == convert_s1[-(n+1)]:
    is_s1_palindrome = True 
else:
    is_s1_palindrome = False
```

The *instant* you detect a difference in equivalent character positions, it ceases to be a palindrome. But you *continue* checking and, if positions start matching again, you re-flag it as a palindrome.

That means it's only the *final* comparison that matters, the one that compares the first and last elements (for the second time).

So something like the non-palindromic `abca` will be considered a palindrome, due to the following checks:

- `a == a`, flag true.
- `b != c`, flag false.
- `c != b`, flag false.
- `a == a`, flag true, this is the final result.

Also take note of that parenthetical "for the second time". There is no reason to go through the entire list since, if `a[0] == a[-1]`, you can be reasonably certain that `a[-1] == a[0]`. Unless you've suborned the `__eq__` dunder method, which I doubt :-)

You only really need to go to the halfway point.

---

As you appear to be learning algorithms rather than a specific language (Python can actually reverse lists and compare them very succinctly), your best bet taking all that into account would be something like:

```py
left = 0                           # left, moving right.
right = len(coll) - 1              # right, moving left.
is_palindrome = True               # assume palindrome to start.
while left < right:                # if different, flag so and stop.
    if coll[left] != coll[right]:
        is_palindrome = False
        break
    left += 1                      # otherwise, move toward center.
    right -= 1
```

In fact, in terms of well structured code, you should look into the `DRY` principle ("Don't repeat yourself").

You can refactor out the palindrome check for a *single* collection and re-use that code for each. And keep in mind, if they're strings, you don't have to turn them into a list first. The snippet `for letter in "abc"` works fine.

Well structured code would be something like:

```py
# This function evaluates one collection by
# starting indexes at the left and right,
# then moving toward the center. It
# compares each character, returning false
# as soon as a mismatch occurs. If it gets
# to the middle without a mismatch, it can
# safely return true.

def is_palin(coll):
    left = 0
    right = len(coll) - 1
    while left < right:
        if coll[left] != coll[right]:
            return False
            break
        left += 1
        right -= 1
    return True

# Returns true if and only if both
# collections are palindromic.

def palindrome(coll_1, coll_2):
    return is_palin(coll_1) and is_palin(coll_2)
```

---

And, although moot in light of this answer, you should be aware that code like:

```py
some_list = list("abc")
for letter in [some_list]: ...
```

will actually give you a *nested* list like `[['a', 'b', 'c']]`.

Hence `letter` will iterate *once,* with the *single* value `['a', 'b', 'c']`, not three times with the *individual* values `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`.

To iterate over the letters, it would be `for letter in some_list: ...`.

---

And just one final note. The actual specifications for the code you need to write *could* be considered ambiguous:

> Write a function that receives two words, in string format, s1 and s2. It should return True, if s1 and s2 are palindromes, and False otherwise.

It's *possible* to interpret that as (so you should probably clarify) asking if `s1` and `s2` are reversals *of each other,* rather than both being palindromes (so something like `s1 == "blub"` and `s2 == "bulb"`).

Technically, that wouldn't make the individual words palindromes, and I base this possible interpretation on little more than the fact the use-case of checking that *two* strings are palindromic is ... unusual.

So it's something you may want to follow up.

Comment: `for letter in [convert_s1]:` is definitely wrong, they put their list (which was unnecessary to begin with) into another list, also, `n = 0` is *inside* the for-loop

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: good point. My answer bypasses that issue but I've mentioned it for extra info anyway, to help out the OP.

Comment: Sorry, Mechanic Pig, we had cross-edit conflict. I've incorporated your fix into mine, so thanks for the input.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using slicing:

```
def palindrome(s1, s2):
    is_s1_palindrome = s1 == s1[::-1]
    is_s2_palindrome = s2 == s2[::-1]
    
    return is_s1_palindrome and is_s2_palindrome
```

Comment: It is not a good answer to provide solution without trying to correct the wrong practices in the problem. (I'm not the down voter)